# Unity - Is there a fast way of calculating the volume of a space where a light is visible?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Given a spotlight in a 3D space, is there a fast way to calculate the volume of the  illuminated area?

It’s fairly trivial to calculate the volume of a simple cone, but any obstructions and areas shadowed by those obstructions must be subtracted.

The end result should, for example, allow me to calculate the probability of a player being able to see the spotlight’s point of origin when being placed at random in its total covered area.

Comment: Simply grab the depth buffer from the point of view of the spotlight and process it.

Comment: ...also I'm pretty sure this was covered in one of the _GPU Gems_ books.

Comment: @MickyD do you have any idea what terms would be best to search for in the GPU Gems books? Since I’m new to this problem and 3D/graphics in general I think my main problem right now is not knowing how to even phrase the question.

Comment: Try "depth buffer" maybe?

Answer (score 0):

By what you're describing it seems like it would be possible to have a raycast from the player camera towards the spotlight and by that you can see if there's anything blocking it.

otherwise maybe you could try calculating it with something like frustum culling [Frustum culling learnopenGL](https://learnopengl.com/Guest-Articles/2021/Scene/Frustum-Culling)

Comment: _"it would be possible to have a raycast from the player camera towards the spotlight and by that you can see if there's anything blocking it"_ - it wouldn't have anything to do with the player.  Instead you would raycast _from the light_ not the player.

Comment: The problem isn’t deciding whether a given point is in shadow, it’s finding the total volume of the cone in shadow.